# Unable to Deploy Next Js SSR app on AWS amplify. ( Internal error on Website and Deployment failed on cli)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I use

- CLI method
- and GUI method ( From AWS website )

When I use CLI method
it says :

```
 Zipping artifacts completed.
⠦ Deploying build artifacts to the Amplify Console..Job failed.{"jobArn":"arn:aws:amplify:eu-central-1:-----:apps/------","jobId":"1","commitId":null,"commitMessage":"Deployment failed","commitTime":null,"startTime":"2021-06-28T12:16:39.969Z","status":"FAILED","endTime":null,"jobType":null}
✔ Deployment complete!
```

And When I use AWS Website
Then it makes the build and after that, it gives an error like

- Starting SSR build ...
- Internal Error ...
- Terminate Logging ...

Comment: I was not able to do that, because at that I was using NextJS 11 version and Amplify does not support that version, So, as a last resort we deployed it to EC2.

Comment: yesterday we resolved it as we were using nestjs 13 so amplify by default using 11 version engine so then we migrated our app to 13 now its working

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's worth noting that the Amplify team has only recently started getting this working, so there are definitely still flaws in the slaw. With that said, I learned in my own project that you need to be using no higher than version "10.2.0" of Next.js right now. Anything newer than that will not build at the moment. As mentioned above, I am sure as they work out the issues they will start supporting newer versions.

Secondly, I would encourage you to join their [Discord server](https://discord.gg/pRHkAAfG) where you can get additional support from the Amplify developers as well as other developers who are actively using the product and working together to sort out some of these issues.

Comment: Hi, I'm using next version 10.2.0, so I'm trying to deploy by aws amplify. But I got the error Deploying build artifacts to the Amplify Console..Job failed.

Comment: With Amplify, u don't have control over the resources that are getting deployed (S3, CloudFront, Lambda@Edge). Have you tried deploying the Next.js app directly using CDK? Here's an example - https://serverless-stack.com/examples/how-to-create-a-nextjs-app-with-serverless.html

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error today and here below are the findings:

> Amplify Hosting does not support manual deploys for server-side rendered (SSR) apps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html

If you navigate to AWS Console -> Amplify -> All apps -> (Your next.js app) -> Hosting environments -> (Click the env, e.g. **dev**), then scroll down to the bottom of the page, you should be able to find some logs saying "Amplify does not support Manual Deploys for SSR.".

Furthermore, here is a recent AWS tutorial that may shed some light: [Deploy a Next.js 13 app to AWS with Amplify Hosting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-next-js-13/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using incremental static page generation than you should deploy the code to vercel
here is the reference
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/ssg-fallback-true-export